# Sync Only Current Branch In Android

Tags: android, cyanogenmod, repo

Lots of places suggest using the `-c` or `--current-branch` option to the `repo` command to reduce the  amount of code downloaded. However, it no longer seems to be available:

```
repo --time -c -j2 sync
Usage: repo [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] COMMAND [ARGS]

main.py: error: no such option: -c
```

Is there an alternative switch now or has the functionality been completely removed?

Can I get an old version of the repo wrapper from somewhere that still has the `-c` switch and use that?

Is there a problem with using `-c`?

My use case is to get a specific branch of CyanogenMod and build a ROM for my phone.

EDIT: Interestingly, the sync.py appears to have the option in it.

```
grep -a2 current-branch .repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py
of a project from server.

The -c/--current-branch option can be used to only fetch objects that
are on the branch specified by a project's revision.

--
                 dest='detach_head', action='store_true',
                 help='detach projects back to manifest revision')
    p.add_option('-c', '--current-branch',
                 dest='current_branch_only', action='store_true',
                 help='fetch only current branch from server')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the edit to the question, the switch is still available.

The confusion has come from the fact that there are actually 2 python scripts in use in `repo --time -c -j2 sync`.

`repo` is one script, it then sends parameters to the `sync` script.

`-c` and `-j` are parameters to the `sync` script and `--time` is a parameter to the `repo` script.

Therefore, the command should be

```
repo --time sync -c -j2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe attribute `upstream` of project element in manifest.xml is a solution for your question.

According to [the document of manifest file](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt)

> Attribute `upstream`: Name of the Git ref in which a sha1 can be found.  Used when syncing a revision locked manifest in -c mode to avoid having to sync the entire ref space.